# Executing Query via C# MVC API

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, api, model-view-controller

I'm having trouble with some code, and I just can't seem to figure this out.  I am attempting to send some data to a backend API that connects to our SQL Server and executes a query that I don't expect any kind of results from.  The problem I'm having is that the SQL command isn't being sent to the server, and I'm getting a "404 - This file doesn't exist".

Here is the front part of the request:

```
public async Task ExportNewLists (string pid, string list)
    {
        var endpointUrl = string.Concat(baseEndpoint, "ExportLists", "/", pid, "/", list);
        AddAuthorization();
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(endpointUrl))
        {
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Response.StatusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;
                var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                var message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseError>(result);
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is the API function I'm trying to call:

```
    [Route("api/Lists/ExportLists/{pid}/{list}")]
    [HttpGet]
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    private async Task<IHttpActionResult> ExportList(string pid, string list)
    {
        using (var connection = db.Database.Connection)
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                var command = connection.CreateCommand();
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandText = "EXEC LIST_EXPORT_SINGLE";
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.Parameters.Add("@PID");
                command.Parameters["@PID"].Value = pid;
                command.Parameters.Add("@LIST");
                command.Parameters["@LIST"].Value = list;
                await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        return Ok();
    }
```

Comment: We can't do anything with "no results" but guess. Please read [ask] and include all relevant details.

Comment: I meant that it literally executes a query that I don't expect to get any kind of result from.  Let me rephrase the paragraph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have marked ExportScrubList as private.  You cannot call an action marked as private via http.

Comment: Ah, this feels like a duh moment! haha Thank you!